# Libgdx - 3d particle blending issue

Tags: libgdx

I try to create simple particle system containing 2 emitters(controllers) : 1 for fire and 1 for smoke. i'm doing it problematically and not using editor. I started with fire and create BilboardParticleBatch set texture and the result was not good at all. The reason is that inside batch the blending function is not correct. So I override it in my own batch and change it to GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE - this produce better results.
So now using my batch the fire is looking good. Then I want to add smoke, so here I want to use Not pre-multiplied blending, so again I created new batch extending BillboardparticleBath and make it to use SRC_ALPHA, ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA and assign it smoke texture. So the smoke is perfect.

The main problem is how to merge both controllers. If I put them both to ParticleEffect and put this Effect in ParticleSystem then I'm able to render them together but the problem is that when particle from both emitters overlaps, sometimes they have wrong blending. It is because probably they are not sorted together as they use 2 batches. The sort is applied not by effect level but by batch level. So this is not a sollution :(

I can try using only one batch and use TextureRegion influencer in order to use different textures for smoke and fire inside 1 batch, but how to solve problem with different blending as it will be one and the same for the batch.

Is it a way somehow to merge both batches in one and tell it to render fire using additive and smoke using just alpha.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. Now it is working fine with 2 batches. I just add depth testing function to the material when override the particle batch.